# Как встроить в поиск в селектор из чекбоксов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой селектор.

```
    <div class="adaptive">
    <dl class="dropdown">
        <dt>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="hida">Поиск...</span>    
            <p class="multiSel"></p>  
        </a>
        </dt>

        <dd>
            <div class="mutliSelect">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="Авиамоторная">
                            <label for="check1">Авиамоторная</label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    ...................                                             
                </ul>
                <div class="order">
                    <button>Применить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

и js к нему

```
 $(".mutliSelect button").hide();

$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
  $(".mutliSelect button").toggle();
});

$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) 
    $(".dropdown dd ul, .mutliSelect button").hide();
});

$('.mutliSelect button').on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
  $(".mutliSelect button").hide();
});

$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 1 ) {
    $('.new').remove();
    $('.multiSel').html('');

    var title = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();

    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.multiSel').append(html);
    $(".hida").hide();
  } 
  else if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 1) {

      $('.multiSel').html('');
      var chk = $('.mutliSelect').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
      var html = '<span class="new"> Выбрано ' + chk + '</span>';
      $('.multiSel').append(html);

  }
  else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".hida");
    $('.multiSel').html('');
    $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

  }
});
```

Состоит он из чекбоксов. 
Как можно встроить в блок с текстом "Поиск..." собственно поиск по этим чекбоксам..

рабочий пример - http://jsfiddle.net/k8cryx7b/

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-List-with-Checkboxes-MultiSelect/

Comment: Зачем он мне?)
У меня вплане чекбоксов проблем нет, а вот с поиском по ним - есть.

Comment: Ну так и нужно спрашивать - как подготовить к отправке запроса, а не встроить)))

Answer (score 0):

Сделал.

Вместо:

```
<span class="hida">Поиск...</span>
```

Нужно:

```
<input class="hida" id="metrosearch" placeholder="Поиск...">
```

и в js добавить

```
$( "#metrosearch" ).on("change paste keyup", function() {
    var query = $(this).val(); 
    $('.metro_option:not(:contains('+ query +'))').hide(); 
    $('.metro_option:contains('+ query +')').show(); 
});
```

И чтобы не учитывался вводимый регистр:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Взято [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746882/jquery-contains-selector-uppercase-and-lower-case-issue)